# How to remove gravatar link from Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to remove gravatar link from wordpress admin but I want to keep the profile picture. How to do this?

Comment: You should visit https://en.support.wordpress.com/gravatars/#upload-an-avatar

Comment: https://en.support.wordpress.com/gravatars/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the gravatar-based avatar link with default avatars in local, you can add the following code fragment to your `functions.php` in your theme.

```
function replace_gravatar_with_default_local_avatar() {
    return some_url_to_default_avatar_image;
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', 'replace_gravatar_with_default_local_avatar' );
```

And if you actually want sort of `cache` or the gravatar, you can establish a cache logic, and use the `get_avatar` hook to handle this. Here is an example of cache logic.

```
function cache_gravatar($avatar) {
    $tmp = strpos($avatar, 'http');
    $g = substr($avatar, $tmp, strpos($avatar, "'", $tmp) - $tmp);
    $tmp = strpos($g, 'avatar/') + 7;
    $f = substr($g, $tmp, strpos($g, "?", $tmp) - $tmp);
    $w = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
    $e = ABSPATH .'avatar/'. $f .'.png';
    $t = dopt('d_avatarDate')*24*60*60; 
    if ( !is_file($e) || (time() - filemtime($e)) > $t )
        copy(htmlspecialchars_decode($g), $e);
    else
        $avatar = strtr($avatar, array($g => $w.'/avatar/'.$f.'.png'));
    if ( filesize($e) < 500 ) 
        copy(get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/img/default.png', $e);
    $avatar = preg_replace("/srcset='([^']*)'/", '', $avatar);
    return $avatar;
}

add_filter('get_avatar','cache_gravatar');
```